# Trained vs randomly initialised cnn model. Difference in inference speed

Tags: keras, cnn

We have 2 models written in Keras. We then convert them to coreml format and test the inference speed of each one on iPhone 7. The model architecture is the same for each of the two. The 1st model is trained on a set of images. the 2nd model's weights are randomly initialized. The number of params is the same for each model, however the speed (in fps) is different (21 vs 13 fps). How's this possible? Why is it so that the trained model is slower, despite the fact that the number of weights and the structure is the same?